# The screen resolution on macOS across different models

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, screen, resolution

I've been using a mbp 15" mid 2015 model since that time, which still performs ok for my needs.

Last year I got a mbp 16" model which is a bit faster, the keyboard is a bit different and there is that Touch Bar which I won't say I prefer (at least ESC key is back).

I use both laptops and I'm starting to develop an opinion about the screen resolution. In the 16" model it seems things look a bit smaller perhaps because pixel wise it has more screen space.

I might prefer things as they look on my old 15" mbp. Can I adjust 16" mbp to have the same pixel size as in 15" mbp?

And additional question: Can any of the new MacBooks (both mbp and air or that MacBook 12") have the same pixel size as in old mid 2015 mbp 15"?

I always use max resolution.

Comment: What scaled resolution do you use on the 2015 MBP?

Comment: The max resolution on both.

Comment: My max, so you mean (on the 15") the retina resolution of 2880x1800 or the highest scaled 1920x1200?  It helps to be precise.

Comment: On 16" 2048x1280 and on 15" 1920x1200. How can I go to 2880x1800?

Comment: I have modified my answer to reflect what you are using now.  The 2880x1800 (if your MBP allows it) would make everything look tiny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MBP 15" mid 2015 has 220 ppi (pixels per inch) with Retina resolution of 2880x1800 pixels and various scaled resolutions (1920x1200, 1680x1050, 1280x800 and 1024x640).

The MBP 16" 2019 has 226 ppi with Retina resolution of 3072x1920 and scaled resolutions 2048x1280, 1792x1120, 1344x840, and 1152x720 pixels. You would be hard pressed to see the difference in size of graphics and texts with the Retina resolution or with corresponding scaled resolutions.

The MBP 14" and 16" 2021 (with M1 Pro or Max SoC) both have 254 ppi with a Retina resolutions of 3024x1964 and 3456x2234 respectively.  The default resolutions are 1523x982 and 1728x1117 and at those resolutions graphics and text will look a bigger than what you are using now.

But both offer scaled resolutions. See, for example, [from 9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2021/10/19/new-macbook-pro-screen-resolution-options/). The 16" has scaled resolutions 2056x1329, 1496x967, 1312x848, 1168 x 755.

The new 16" scaled to 2056x1329 is close to the 2048x1280 you are using now - graphics and text looking only lightly smaller.

And for the 14", the highest scaled 1800x1169 will produce similar sized text and graphics.

I am sure you would find a resolution that will suit your working and not be very different to what you have now.

Comment: And in current MacBook Air we find 1680 by 1050, 1440 by 900 and 1024 by 640.

Comment: Is want to add an external ultra wide monitor and I don't want to use scaling as it ran slower and made the laptop spin the fans all the time. Which (34") monitor can be used? Anyone with experience?